# Mysql create new rows from column content on column id

Tags: mysql

Sorry, I couldn't explain on title clearly. I have a table that has rows like

```
    qid     |     content
    --------------------
    1         name1
    2         surname1
    3         feature1
    1         name2
    2         surname2
    3         feature2
    1         name3
    2         surname3
    3         feature3
    4         x3
    1         name4
    2         surname4
    3         feature4
```

I want to create an sql query related to qids to create the table below

```
    column1   |  column2   |  column3   |   column4
    -----------------------------------------------
    name1        surname1     feature1      NULL
    name2        surname2     feature2      NULL
    name3        surname3     feature3      x3
    name4        surname4     feature4      NULL
```

NULL for qid 4 is not important.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to select by qid and created columns one by one. select content from table where qid = 1, than qid=2 than=3.. But combining them is very difficult because there isnt some of the qids like 4.

Comment: is there also a auto increment field, to see which row is the next after the first, else there is no sort order and you cant do it

Comment: Yes there is an auto increment column.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. As such, this problem is essentially insoluble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [MySQL variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) and [If](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) conditions while selecting rows and go according to the `qid` value.

- If `qid` is less than the value required for a particular column, we print an empty value, else we assign it to a variable. We carry previous column values for next rows which is necessary to bring them to a combined state.
- We reassign variables to empty values if we find `qid` got reset for next set of rows.
- In the end, we do a group by `column1` and take `max()` of every column to bring lexicographically largest values for each value of `column1`. This also filters out duplicate rows which aren't fully formed till 4<sup>th</sup> column.
- **Note that** this works under the assumption that rows are in order of belonging to each other consecutively, meaning, `surname1` can't appear after 10 rows of row of `name1`.

**SQL:**

```
select max(column1),max(column2),max(column3),max(column4)
from ( select if(qid = 1,@column1 := content,@column1) as column1,
              if(qid = 2,@column2 := content,if(qid < 2,@column2 := '',@column2)) as column2,
              if(qid = 3,@column3 := content,if(qid < 3,@column3 := '',@column3)) as column3,
              if(qid = 4,@column4 := content,if(qid < 4,@column4 := '',@column4)) as column4
from test , (select @column1 := '',@column2 := '',@column3 := '',@column4 := '') init_variables) derived
group by column1;
```

**Demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wqdRkhF5uWGDCweZX4w8rS/0

Comment: Thank you very much. Query took a bit long time but it worked.

Comment: I used this code @Alex. Your code is nearly same as this but i didnt try your code. Thank you.

Comment: @SerkanS I suggest you to try both and go with the most optimal one for your case.

Comment: Thanks very much @vivek_23, Alex. I tried it too. They are nearly same.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely normalize your data. The approach I've made is very fragile, because you have no clear `GROUP BY` column to group records in one line.

But so far, just to give you some direction:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPzJGtFy6yZDACtaubYJbo/0

```
SELECT 
     MAX(t.name),
     MAX(t.surname),
     MAX(t.feature),
     MAX(t.x)
FROM (
SELECT
   IF(t.qid = 1, @row:=@row+1, @row) `row`,
   IF(t.qid = 1, content, null) `name`,
   IF(t.qid = 2, content, null) `surname`,
   IF(t.qid = 3, content, null) `feature`,
   IF(t.qid = 4, content, null) `x`
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) row) t
GROUP BY t.row;
```

You've said in comment that you have some auto incremental column.
You can use that to order in subquery:

```
...
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row := 0) row
ORDER BY my_autoincremental_column) t
...
```

Comment: this is not working because the sort order is not guaranteed if there is  no order by clause

Comment: @BerndBuffen it is working with dataset provided by OP and fiddle you can see has proof. The problem is not my answer but the original problem described in post